# How to set socket InpuStreamReader timeout in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I need to set timeout on socket in Java. When `InputStreamReader is` doesn't get any message from server it will skip the `is.readLine()` without closing the socket. If I use `s.setSoTimeout(5000)`, it will close the socket. I don't want to close the socket, only skip a readLine(). How can I do it?

Comment: `InputStreamReader` doesn't have a method `readLine()` and `setSoTimeout(..)` so you this question is wrong.

Comment: I didn't use setSoTimeout  for InputStreamReader, I use it for the socket

Comment: No. I didn't use it for readline. But I want to skip a readline if the server doesn't give any response in 5000ms

Comment: I see, Ok you could use a `Future` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html combined with the `ready()` method of your current `InputStreamReader`